# How to disable internal django tests?

Tags: django, unit-testing

I installed django and wrote some small app. After I tried to run my tests with ./manage.py test and saw that django ran 419 tests, but I wrote only 2 of them. As i understand it`s some kind of internal Django tests. How I can disabled them and where are they actually from?
I use virtualenv and this is result of pip freeze:

- Django==1.4.3
- South==0.7.6
- argparse==1.2.1
- wsgiref==0.1.2
- yolk==0.4.3

First of all i googled and dissabled south tests with SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE=False and SKIP_SOUTH_TESTS=True in my setting.py but nothing changed

**SOLVED**: Solved when I install django-nose

Comment: `django-nose` does this

Answer (score 1):

You can choose app for which you whant to run test:

```
python ./manage.py test <my_app_name>
```